# AJAX Post request not working with Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I can do this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: '/someurl/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Web:

```
Route::get('/someurl','MyController@myfunction');
```

And it works just fine, but when I try the same with post:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: '/someurl/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

Route::post('/someurl','MyController@myfunction');
```

I get a 405 method not allowed error message in the console

Comment: `Route::get(` <===

Comment: Change `Route::get` to `Route::post` ?

Comment: And then go get coffee

Comment: If you change the code `Route::get` to `Route::post`,don't forget `CSRF` token as well, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Does the trailing slash matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another route with

`Route::post('/someurl','MyController@myfunction');`

By the way u are not sending any data, in post we need to send data right..

Also check whether csrf token is being passed in data, if not as mentioned above try adding it manually.

If you are using `{{Form...}}` it would be automatically added to form data.

Answer (score 2):

`POST` using normal ajax need `CSRF Token` to be pass in `POST Method`

in your ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: '/someurl/',
        dataType: 'json',  
        data : {"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"}  //pass the CSRF_TOKEN()
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

or

set head meta tag

```
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

set header ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```